# Change scrollspeed for ctrl+arrows in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I don't want to take my hands of the keyboard every time i scroll in a document so i have started to use ctrl+up and ctrl+down a lot.
But it's so sloooooow, is there any way to make it scroll more than one row per click?

Comment: Re#er allows you to alt+up/down through methods. :)

Comment: I have never found scrolling to the top of methods to be useful.  Ctrl-F to find the one I want.  I wish I could find the right Google search term to find out how to set Visual Studio 2015 to scroll 1 line using Ctr+Up and Ctrl+Down..!!!

Answer (score 3):

Whenever keyboard fatigue strikes, [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) will always save the day!

This AutoHotkey macro should do the trick:

```
 ^DOWN::
 send ^{DOWN}^{DOWN}^{DOWN} ;send Ctrl+Down 3 times
 return

 ^UP::
 send ^{UP}^{UP}^{UP}       ;send Ctrl+Up 3 times
 return
```

It is quite a coarse solution but it does seem to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In your control panel "Keyboard Properties" you can set the Character repeat options.  You can tune Repeat delay (long<->short) and Repeat rate (slow<->fast).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Auto Hot Key comment, I would like to post the script I use:

```
#SingleInstance Force
#CommentFlag //

// Script affects scroll speed only when Visual Studio window is active.
#IfWinActive, [Name of Project] - Microsoft Visual Studio

// Ctrl+Up = Ctrl+Up * 20
^Up::
    Send, ^{Up 20}
    Return

// Ctrl+Down = Ctrl+Down * 20
^Down::
    Send, ^{Down 20}
    Return

// Scroll Up = Scroll Up * 20
WheelUp::
    Send, {WheelUp 15}
    Return

// Scroll Down = Scroll Down * 20
WheelDown::
    Send, {WheelDown 15}
    Return

// Pressing Escape stops the script.
Esc::ExitApp
```

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible with the default key bindings in Visual Studio.  They only allow for a single row scroll at a time.

You can potentially do this by building a Macro and running the command Edit.MoveControlUp multiple times.

Comment: Hmm, creating a macro worked but it's not responsive enough to be used for this kind of thing. When i start the macro the screen flashes, the cursor changes to a wait-cursor, the taskbar pops up because a new icon in the notifyarea appears(got taskbar on autohide) and an annoying baloon tooltip appears. :(

Answer (score 0):

PgUp & PgDn works for me.  I hate using the mouse.

Comment: PgUp & PgDn scrolls too much and it also moves the input-cursor. (btw, is it possible to decrease the length of pgup/dn-scroll, to only scroll half a page instead of the entire screen height?)

Answer (score 0):

You say "per click", I'm guessing you mean by every click of the mouse wheel.

I found an simple plugin that gives a nitrous boost to the scroll speed when you hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd>

**Mouse Fast Scroll**: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/17c06288-98de-46bc-97ba-4f468bf8a431

The <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is usually close by my "keyboard" hand, and in combination with the mouse is faster than the <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> keys.

It's also nice that the speed is "normal" when you don't hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, so you can have precision as well.